How can I provide a custom LLMTool to the current chatbook?
I wrote a useful LLMTool that works well with LLMSynthesize, but now I want to chat with it using the full chatbook interface. Is there a way to add that tool to the current notebook's LLMConfiguration? Or create a new notebook with a given LLMConfiguration?
